# Escaping parenthesis in gawk in windows

Tags: windows, awk, escaping, gawk, parentheses

I am facing a rather strange issue when trying to escape a parenthesis in awk. My file has the following line

```
79-Au-196 isomer state population  0.153658     mb (m1 E= 0.5957MeV Jp=-12.0)
```

So I want to extract column 5 (i.e. 0.153658). To do that I am running the following

```
>gawk "/79-Au-196 isomer state population/{if($7=="\(m1")print $5}" Au_test.out
```

and what I get is

> ```
> > gawk: /79-Au-196 isomer state population/{if($7==\(m1)print $5} gawk: 
> >                                                  ^ backslash not last character on line
> ```

I tried replacing `"\(m2"` with `"%s(m2"` or `'\(m2'` but nothing actually worked.

Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: Just use single quotes instead of double, like this: `gawk '/79-Au-196 isomer state population/{if($7=="(m1")print $5}'`

Comment: @randomir : Thanks a lot for your comment. I also tried this, but I got the following `gawk: '/79-Au-196
gawk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression`

Comment: @randomir: Good advice in general (Unix platforms), but the OP is running the command on _Windows_.

Comment: @mklement0, You're right. I haven't used Windows in a while. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

```
gawk "/79-Au-196 isomer state population/{if($7==\"(m1\")print $5}" Au_test.out
```

---

- On *Windows*, you *must* use `"..."` (double quote) around your `gawk` script.

  - `'...'` quoting (single quotes) - which should always be used to delimit `awk` scripts on *Unix* platforms - is not recognized by `cmd.exe`.
- This then requires `\`-escaping any `"` instances *inside* the script.
- By contrast, `(` (the parenthesis) does *not* need escaping in `$7==\"(m1\"`, because from `gawk`'s perspective you're using it inside a *string literal* that is compared to a field value with `==`.